# WEB.API Core , Server Query To Microsoft Graph or Outlook

Tags: asp.net-core

There are three methods to send Email by Outlook in WEB.API Core .

1. I can use directly JSon query for Microsoft Graph API or for
   Outlook API directly;
2. I can use library Microsoft.Graph;
3. I can send in WEB.API Core from program Outlook in the
   computer .

In first two situations I must manually with browser log in. 
Third way is does not satisfied me cause at server can not be program Outlook .

Is it possible to get Authorization and Authentication without browser, from my server directly ?

Comment: Hi, if you want to send email from a web application you are much better looking at doing it server side, is that not possible?

Comment: Hello @MandyShaw ! That what I asked for , that is was are question , if it possible and if affirmatively how . If you have somethink to add to my answer I will glade to hear here from you ! Thank you very much !

Comment: I have no idea what is available within your specific web application environment, but whatever I have used has always had some sort of SMTP API (with or without MIME and/or encryption of some sort), which you would typically use to get the outgoing email as far as Exchange for onward relaying (which an Exchange admin would need to configure). Alternatively, although I would personally be nervous of doing this, you could send the email straight out to the recipient over SMTP (which would obviously require firewall work, & you'd need to be sure that any file sent had been anti-virus'd, etc.)

Comment: P.S. the other benefit of letting Exchange take the strain is that it would do any outgoing mail logging, etc., required by your organisation.

Comment: Yes you right ! Thank you @MandyShaw ! I already solved this question . I will make an addition in my answer .

Answer (score 0):

My Solution for send Email like from Outlook is I must interact with Exchange Web Service . So this is that what I looking for . This is the four's way for interaction with Outlook . And the best incarnation for this is packet Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Client Credentials Grant Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) , in this scenario , your web api will call Microsoft Graph to send emails with their own identity and not on behalf of a user ,then no login process :

[Get access without a user using Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)

Comment: Thank You @Nan Yu ! It is very useful !